# Is $\max \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{\pi (1 + x^2 + f ' (x)^2 )} $ a uniqueness condition here?

Tags: optimization, improper-integrals, tetration

Let f(x) be a real-differentiable function with $f′(x)>0,f′′(x)>0 $ and

$$ f(f(x)) = \exp(x) $$

for all real $x$.

Tommy1729 adds the optimization condition

$$ max \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{\pi (1 + x^2 + f ' (x)^2 )} $$

Is this a uniqueness condition ?
How to prove or disprove it ?

---

If not how many solutions are there ?

If there are infinitely many , are they countable ? Are they simply connected ?

What can we say about the solutions ?

---

Is there a similar looking optimization condition that is a uniqueness condition ?

Comment: I can't believe nobody has created the uniqueness tag yet !  (I can not do it from this mobile , < not supported > )